# Xcode GPS location manager access message

Tags: iphone, gps, cllocationmanager, xcode5

How can I do the following please?
I have a button in my iPhone app that the user clicks to start GPS navigation. All I do when the button is clicked is get their location, and pass it to Google maps to do the rest.

However, as soon as I land on the screen where the button is, the application ask me the standard "This app would like to use your current location". But I dont want this to be asked as soon as I land on the screen. Instead, it should be asked when the button is clicked.

Here is how I handle the scenario in my views .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And then when the button is clicked. Also tried to put the code from viewDidLoad here as can be seen from the commented out section. This works in that I dont get asked the question when the view loads, but then the GPS does not work once button is clicked. I get an error message on the app screen saying "The app was unable to establish a route to the nearest road". And the "This app would like to access your current location" only flashes up on the screen briefly.

```
- (IBAction)gpsNavigation:(id)sender
{
/*
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
*/

NSString *destAddress = @"52.269444, -9.708674";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f%f&daddr=%@",
                 locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,
                 locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude,
                 [destAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use commented code in gpsNavigation: method.
Your problem is that you get locationManager.location as soon as you call [locationManager startUpdatingLocation].
So your code can be as following.

```
- (IBAction)gpsNavigation:(id)sender
{
     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
     locationManager.delegate = self;
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSString *destAddress = @"52.269444, -9.708674";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f%f&daddr=%@",
                     locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,
                     locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude,
                     [destAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you call `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` your app request locations and will ask the user for permission. So delay this call untill you need it (button pressed)